# Substitute function calculates SymPy expression

Tags: python, sympy, substitution

Let's say I have an equation:

```
 equation = d1*d2
```

If I use substitute function:

```
equation.subs({d1: 20, d2:10})
```

Python will output 200 instead of 20*10.
How can I only substitute symbols with numbers and not calculate the expression?
I am using SymPy, and print equation in LaTeX form, then copy them to Word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print substituted expression without numerical evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331069/print-substituted-expression-without-numerical-evaluation)

Answer (score -1):

did you mean something like this?

```
>>> equation = "d1*d2"
>>> equation
'd1*d2'
>>> equation.replace("d1","20").replace("d2","10")
'20*10'
```

Comment: If i do that, i can't calculate the value of the expression later on. I am using sympy by the way, and i copy the equation to word so i need it to be pretty (latex equation).

Comment: @VELIKIUM you can then eval the expresion: eval("20*10") or eval(some_string). (take caution with evals). But I don't know sympy