# Print substituted expression without numerical evaluation

Tags: python, sympy

Is it possible to print a substitute SymPy expression without calculation? I want to print both substituted express and result.

e.g.

```
x = Symbol('x')
expr = x**2
pprint(expr) # this prints expression
result = expr.subs({x:2}) 
print(result) # this print result 4
```

How can I print the "middle result", the expression `2**2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in `UnevaluatedExpr` for this purpose, as shown below:

```
result = expr.subs(x, UnevaluatedExpr(2))
print(result)   # prints 2**2 
result = result.doit()
print(result)   # prints 4
```

Documentation: [Prevent expression evaluation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#prevent-expression-evaluation)